# File Handling Questions

Tags: php, linux

What if I `file_get_contents()` a file while it is being processed by `file_put_contents()`. Will the file get the past contents of the file or the current contents that are not yet finished writing?

Comment: what do you mean with "while"? Concurrent process/threads or ... ?

Answer (score 0):

`file_get_contents()` will read the incomplete file, because `file_put_contents()` writes the file buffered. You will have this effect especially for large files.

**Edit**: Note (because it came up in another comment):

You can use the LOCK_EX flag to apply a lock.

```
file_put_contents ( $filename, $content, LOCK_EX );

$content = file_get_contents ( $filename, LOCK_EX );
```

Comment: Yes very small files will be written atomically. But in general, these functions are not atomic.

Answer (score -1):

If one process tries to access a file while another is writing to it, the one reading will be locked until the write is complete - this is why if you're using file-based sessions and have PHP files like:

```
// a.php:
session_start();
sleep(60);

// b.php:
session_start();
echo "Hi!";
```

Then if you load `a` followed by `b` in different browser tabs, `b` will hang until `a` has finished. This is because `a` has locked the session file, and `b` is waiting for the lock to be released.

The same applies to `file_get_contents`/`file_put_contents`.

Comment: This is wrong. There is no locking that applies to file_get_contents/file_put_contents.

Comment: @KenyakornKetsombut Citation needed

Comment: @djay check the docs http://au1.php.net/file_put_contents and look for LOCK_EX